# action performed java dont run?

Tags: java, view, actionlistener

Good morning, I'm a bit new to java, I'm trying to create a dynamically loaded graphical application, the application has a frame with a panel that changes depending on which button is pressed, the problem is that when I create an additional view and the panel is changed the program does not enter the actionPerformed of the controller of the last created view.

this is my code:

This is the controller that contains the basic framework of the application and a panel that changes dynamically when you press the btnInventory button.

```
package pointofsale.controllers;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import pointofsale.views.HomeView;

/**
 *
 * @author dragonyte
 */
public class HomeController extends Controller implements ActionListener{

    HomeView view;

    public HomeController() {
        this.view = new HomeView();
        this.view.setResizable(false);
        this.view.setVisible(true);
        
        this.view.btnInventory.addActionListener(this);
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if(ae.getSource()==this.view.btnInventory){
            new InventoryController(this.view.pnDinamic);
        }
    }
    
}
```

this is InventoryController:

```
package pointofsale.controllers;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import pointofsale.views.inventory.InventoryView;

/**
 *
 * @author dragonyte
 */
public class InventoryController extends Controller implements ActionListener{
    
    private InventoryView view;

    public InventoryController(JPanel panel) {
        this.view = new InventoryView();
        
        InventoryMenuController a = new InventoryMenuController(panel);
        this.addViewWhitoutRefresh(this.view, panel);
        
        this.view.btnPrint.addActionListener(this);
    }

    
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        if(ae.getSource()==this.view.btnPrint){
            new NewUnitController();
        }
    } 
}
```

pressing the print button calls a controller that creates a modal window, this is the controller:

```
package pointofsale.controllers.modal;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import pointofsale.views.modal.NewUnitView;

/**
 *
 * @author dragonyte
 */
public class NewUnitController implements ActionListener{
    
    private NewUnitView view;

    public NewUnitController() {
        
        this.view = new NewUnitView(null, true);
        this.view.setResizable(false);
        this.view.setVisible(true);
        
        this.view.btnSave.addActionListener(this);
        
        
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        Object source = ae.getSource();
        if(source==this.view.btnSave){
            System.out.print("ok");
        }      
    }
}
```

up to here it works correctly change screens and create the modal window the problem is that when pressing the btnSave button of the modal window it does not enter the actionPerformed of the class and therefore it does not print "ok"

I already tried to put the owner of the screen but it didn't work.
and also try it with a JPanel instead of a modal window.
I have noticed that it happens to the third controller loaded.
and the console does not print any error or exception.

I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I already managed to solve it, I just had to define the addActionListener event before making the modal window visible:

```
public class NewUnitController implements ActionListener{
    
    private NewUnitView view;

    public NewUnitController() {
        
        this.view = new NewUnitView(null, true);
        this.view.setResizable(false);
        //definded before -----------
        this.view.btnSave.addActionListener(this);

        this.view.setVisible(true);
        
        
        
        
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        Object source = ae.getSource();
        if(source==this.view.btnSave){
            System.out.print("ok");
        }      
    }
}
```